# Powershell Modify large SQL File

Tags: powershell

We have 23 GB SQL file that cannot be opened in any text file, so I am trying to use a Powershell Script.

`((Get-Content D:\test.sql) -replace 'XXY','UUUUU') |Set-Content D:\test.sql`

The problem is that it takes too long time, the text I want to modify stays in 1st 20 line, so I tried

`((Get-Content D:\test.sql) |Select -First 20 -replace 'xxxx','UUUU') |Set-Content D:\test.sql`

No luck, no errors nothing happens Am I missing anything?

Comment: Not that it can't be done using Powershell but try HxD editor. You'll be amazed.

Comment: the `streamreader/writer` stuff in dotnet can be called from PoSh. it would allow you to read in a limited number of lines at any one time. if that is too different from your usual style, you can take a look at the `-ReadCount` parameter of `Get-Content` for ways to limit the current number of lines in RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here two options to speed up the reading/writing process.
Both read one line at a time, replace the stuff you need replaced and write that line to a **new** output file.

The first makes use of the .NET [System.IO.File ReadLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.8) method:

```
foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("D:\test.sql")) {
    Add-Content -Path 'D:\test2.sql' -Value ($line -replace 'XXY','UUUUU')
}
```

Perhaps even faster that the above, would be to use .Net [System.IO.StreamReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=netframework-4.8) and [System.IO.StreamWriter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=netframework-4.8):

```
$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader("D:\test.sql")
$writer = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\test2.sql")
while (($line = $reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    $writer.WriteLine(($line -replace 'XXY','UUUUU'))
}
$reader.Dispose()
$writer.Dispose()
```